# how to understand a matrix with order $O(n^{-1})$

Tags: matrices

I am reading a paper in which an assumption is that a matrix (for example $A_{n\times n}$) is $O(n^{-1})$. I have difficulty to understand that assumption. Does that mean the norm of the matrix is $O(n^{-1})$? I also noticed that the row number and column number of A are both n. Will it affect the order?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: You mixed matrix and norm of matrix

Comment: Some context would be good. Out of context I would think that it would mean the norm is $O(n^{-1})$, but it could mean the entries. These are not the same even in fixed dimension, and as $n \to \infty$ you also lose norm equivalence, since the constants in the statement of norm equivalence can blow up or go to zero. Think about the vector with all entries $1/n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ for an example. So the precise details of the statement matter.

Comment: The link to the paper is as follows. In (3) $R_n$ is a matrix (random) of $o_p(n^{-1})$ and its expectation is $o(n^{-1})$. http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/~wiens/home%20page/pubs/wls%20with%20estimated%20weights.pdf

Comment: It seems that the $C_i$ are intended to be bounded in $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ where $N$ is fixed, and $n<N$ (the number of "sample locations") is variable.